# Issue related to JsRender dynamic template rendering

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I have an issue applying template to JsRender at runtime.

Please refer to this image -
[image: Software Genius Inc.]

When i click on Execute Model button i m fetching data from controller and caching on client side within an on object (resultData).

If i use hardcoded template it works. Here is the code

```
$.templates({ tmpl: "{{:#index+1}}:<b>ID=>{{:ItemID}}</b>- <i>Name=>{{:ItemName}}</i> - (Rate=>{{:Rate}}) <br />" });
$( "#outputWindow" ).html( $.render [ "tmpl" ]( resultData ));
```

When i am clicking on any of the style then i have to apply dynamic template. I am also able to get the dynamic template. 
Please check this image -
[image: Software Genius Inc.]

Below is my code what i am trying to apply -

```
// Apply selected style
    function applyThisStyle(stl) {
        var id = $(stl).parent().find('#hidScannerId').val();
        var styleName = stl.innerHTML.toString().trim();
        alert('Applying style : ' + stl.innerHTML+ ', id='+id);

        //var styleText = "";
        var thisScanner = scannerDictionary[id];

        for(var i=0;i<thisScanner.Styles.length;i++) {
            if (thisScanner.Styles[i].Name == styleName) {
                alert(styleName);
                var styleText = thisScanner.Styles[i].HTMLContent;
                renderMyTemplate(styleText);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    // Render template based on style selection
    function renderMyTemplate(t) {
        alert ("Template = " + t);
        $.templates({ tmpl: t });
        $( "#outputWindow" ).html( $.render [ "tmpl" ]( resultData ));
    }
```

Can anybody tell me whats wrong with code. Why dynamic template is not applied while hardcoded is working.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error or anything? Does anything get added to the DOM when you try to render the dynamic template?  It's difficult to see in the image, but in your template does it have `{{SimMovAvg}}`?

Comment: This may be due to the template not being compiled before you display the result of the rendered template; I run into this before.  You can confirm it by throwing in a `debugger;` call somewhere in the code and waiting a bit, then trying your problem again.  If it renders, then you need to wait for the template to compile before you display it.  Also, `$( "#outputWindow" ).html( $.render [ "tmpl" ]( resultData ));` should be `$( "#outputWindow" ).html( $.render.tmpl( resultData ));`